# Block not displaying on my twig template

Tags: templates, drupal, twig, block

This is my template info

```
name: Estar Mejor
type: theme
description: "Tema de estar mejor"
core: 8.x
package: custom
version: 1.0
base theme: classy

regions:
  header: "Header"
  social: "Social Buttons"
  primary_menu: "Nav Menu"
  breadcrumb: "Breadcrumb"
  content: "Content"
  sidebar_first: "Sidebar"
  footer: "Footer"

libraries:
  - estarmejor/base
```

I create a template `page--front.html.twig` 
Page and views are displaying correctly.

```
<header id="navbar" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
       {{ page.header }}
       {{ drupal_view('slider_header') }}
    </div>
</header>
```

But when I put a block it doesn't work.

```
<header id="navbar" role="banner">
    <div class="container">
       {{ drupal_block('estarmejor_branding') }}
    </div>
</header>
```

`Twig_Error_Syntax: Unknown "drupal_block" function. en Twig_ExpressionParser->getFunctionNodeClass()`

[Block Id is correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8pE4.png)

When I install twig tweak it shows me `Este bloque está deteriorado o desaparecido. Puede que esté perdiendo contenido. Es posible que tenga que activar el módulo original.`

I'm using Drupal v8.4.3

Answer (score 2):

You have to install module for it [twig_tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak) and [twig_extensions](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_extensions) For more [details](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/207377/programatically-print-blocks-in-twig)